# Extract feeds/post/comments of a group

Tags: chatter-groups

Im trying to extract feeds/post/comments of a group i have used dataloader but im getting 0 data extracted, in there any other way i can extract the feeds?

Help please

Answer (score 2):

According to the help docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Exporting-Chatter-feeds&language=en_US) you need to make sure you click on the check-box “Show all Salesforce objects” and then select “Group Feed (CollaborationGroupFeed)” object. To filter a specific group you should use the group Id. If you are doing all of the above and still getting 0 results, try not filtering and see if you get anything that way.